# The best way to find out wether some threads are blocked using performance profiler?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, profiling, dottrace

I am using dotTrace 2017 form jetBrains. 
My goal is to improve performance of some WPF components on the page. 
It seems that typical improvements like simplifying Visual Tree, freezing IFreezables, avoiding resources duplicatons and some more does not give a desired effect. 
Since the UI itself is not so complicated and mainly is data view: textboxes, chechboxex, few buttons, tabes and so on - without any sophisticated animations, or other rendering-intensive things... it seems to me that the problem hides somewhere deeper.

Project relies heavily on reactive extensions, so I am strarting to suspect that some threads, responsible for collecting the data from the databases, are simply blocked. But I am not sure **which is the easiest and trustable way to check out?** Should I simpy try to sum up the time, when background threads were waiting? Maybe there is some more specific tool to use? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're running this under Visual Studio? All you have to do is get it running and hit the "pause" button. Then go to each thread and display the call stack. It will tell you in as much detail as you could possibly want what each thread is waiting for.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use Timeline profiling mode? It's very useful for solving threading issues.